# Getting Parse error for LUA and WWW license on swupdate yocto

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, swupdate

running meta-swupdate recipe for yocto on dunfell branch, getting error for license of bot lua and www in swupdate.inc file

New to this field, help would be really appreciated. Building for octavo

In conf/local.conf: I set MACHINE = "osd32mp1-brk"

```
**`ERROR: ParseError at /home/affan/swupdate/meta-swupdate/recipes-support/swupdate/swupdate.inc:10: unparsed line: 'LICENSE:${PN}-lua = "LGPLv2+"'`**
```

[image: Image for error]

Answer (score 0):

got it solved, it mainly a syntax error. It was supposed to be fixed in dunfell branch but for whatever reason it was still there.
had to replace **:** with **_**.
LICENSE:${PN}-lua--->LICENSE_${PN}-lua

had this parsing error in multiple lines and files, listing the file names here:
swupdate.inc
swupdate-lualoader_1.0.bb
cpio_%.bbappend
initscripts-swupdate-usb.bb
mtd-utils_%.bbappend
luafilesystem_git.bb
luasocket_git.bb
takeui_1.12.bb
cpio_%.bbappend